# Joomla can't open template directory

Tags: joomla

When I open `example.com/templates/something.php` I get error

```
The requested URL /templates/ was not found on this server.

Apache Server at example.com Port 80
```

If I try open in localhost it work fine but in hosting not. what can be wrong ?

Comment: Why are you trying to directly access a template file?  With Joomla, you shouldn't need to open template files directly.

Comment: Even so, that's not relevant, if you try to request [a file like that from Joomla's official site](http://www.joomla.org/templates/joomla12/component.php) on a browser it returns 200 OK. Is your virtualhost properly set? What happens when you request example.com alone?